# How would one analyse the solutions to this non linear ODE system?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I've come upon the following system of ODEs, where $f_1, f_2, f_3 : I \subset \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$:

$$f_1^2 + f_2^2 = 1$$
$$(f_1')^2 + (f_2')^2 + (f_3')^2 = 1$$
$$-f_2f_1'' + f_1f_2'' = (f_1'')^2 + (f_2'')^2 + (f_3'')^2 $$

I'm trying to find solutions (even trivial ones, really) but it hasn't been easy. What would be some useful restrictions on $f_1, f_2$ and $f_3$? If it's too much of a task to find particular solutions, how can one best understand this system?

Oh, and if anyone knows whether there's a way to tackle this using numerical methods I'd appreciate it too.

Comment: Have you tried for example polar-coordinates (on the first two coordinates)? I do not have a solution yet, but it seems promising.

Comment: @WalterJ I'm not sure I understand your suggestion. How can polar coordinates help me here?

Comment: I meant using the problem structure directly, i.e. $(f_1,f_2)$ living on the circle and $(\dot{f}_1,\dot{f}_2,\dot{f}_3)$ living on the sphere. This might give you a lot more intuition, but it requires some work. For example the first equation can become $\dot{r}(t)=0$, $r(t_0)=1$, for $r$ some radius.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first two equations say this is a motion on the cylinder with speed $1$.
One family of trivial solutions is where the motion is in the $f_3$ direction only:
$$ f_1(t) = \cos(\alpha),\ f_2(t) = \sin(\alpha), \ f_3(t) = t + c$$

EDIT: Following WalterJ's suggestion, if $f_1(t) = \cos(g(t))$ and $f2(t)=\sin(g(t))$, the first equation is satisfied automatically and the last two become
$$ \eqalign{\dot{g}^2 + \dot{f_3}^2 &= 1 \cr
     \ddot{g} = \dot{g}^4 + \ddot{g}^2 + \ddot{f_3}^2\cr}$$

We can then eliminate $f_3$ from this: note that
$$ \dot{f_3} \ddot{f_3} = - \dot{g} \ddot{g} $$
so $$\ddot{f_3}^2 = \dfrac{\dot{g}^2 \ddot{g}^2}{1-\dot{g}^2} $$

and thus we get one equation for $g$:
$$ \ddot{g} = \dot{g}^4 + \ddot{g}^2 + \dfrac{\dot{g}^2 \ddot{g}^2}{1-\dot{g}^2} $$
Note this is a separable (but rather nasty) first-order equation in $\dot{g}$.

Comment: Do you mean that the equation is separable if we solve for $\ddot{g}$?

Comment: I just arrived at something almost equivalent to your edit, I'm glad I saw it! Thanks for the help

Comment: This is also what I got, but I desperately tried to simplify the last expression

Comment: @Evgeny I mean that if you write $\dot{g} = v$, the equation $\dot{v} = v^4 + \dot{v}^2 + \dfrac{v^2 \dot{v}^2}{1-v^2}$ is separable.  You have to first solve a quadratic to get it in the form $\dot{v} = f(v)$.